# How can I restrict access to default azure website?

Tags: azure, web

We are experiencing a Dodos attack (I guess) as we are receiving millions of HEAD request to our web site.
We have secured it but unfortunately Azure has the default domain xyz.azurewebsite.com and the "attacker" is making request to that URL. Even if I add a network restriction the server still goes down as to produce the "403 forbidden" page I guess it uses some resource.
Any Ideas to prevent this ?

Comment: How is your web site hosted? App Service? IIS? AKS?

Comment: @Shiraz xyz.azurewebsite.com should give you a hint ;-)

Comment: You should open a support ticket

Comment: @ShirazBhaiji App Service

Comment: @CSharpRocks, Yes I should have seen that :)

Comment: Can you see any more detail on the Http 403 response. Is it 403.x, if so which number is x?